Formatting Specific Rows/Columns/Entries in pgfplotstable
I have an external program to compute several tables that I will then place in TeX (separately) using pgfplotstable. The table will have possibly a dozen columns and hundreds of rows with various types of entries. I need certain rows/columns/entries to have specified formatting.
The pgfplotstable's documentation makes it clear how to do by labeling the rows/columns and applying formatting to a labeled row/column or how to do systematic formatting, e.g. every other row is shaded gray. However, I do not see from the documentation how to implement what I am looking to do. Given the number of rows/columns, labeling is out of the question (insofar as I see).
As a concrete example, my program might produce a table that when loaded into text using pgfplotstable looks like this:

The table I want has specific properties: the row labels are rounded to 1 decimal, the column labels rounded to 3 decimals, the "interior" table entries rounded to 2 decimals, and a specific entry to break the rounding rules and be loaded from the data with highlight, e.g. bold face (maybe perhaps if they are above 10).


@I would suggest if you have 100s of rows as you say, generate  the TeX side as well this way. Rounding etc in \pgfplotstables would be too slow and cumbersome.

@yannisl The issue is that all the values in these tables are difficult computations that each require numerical techniques far beyond what TeX offers, so they really need to be performed by an external program. I simply need TeX to display the end results in a particular way.

You misunderstood my comment, I am saying, use your program to generate the data. Depending on the format of the generated data, use an the external program (or another script) to transform it to a simple longtable including all the rounding and mark-up. Then import it with \input. So you have a) data b) transformed data c) data in TeX format. I did this at work for many years. If you add a couple of real lines of data output from your program I will make some suggestions. What computer language you use to generate the data?

@yannisl Ah, yes, I see what you mean. This would be tedious to do this for the various programs I have but I had considered this. I was hoping there was something simple on the TeX end that experts such as yourself would know about to avoid this. But I suppose at worst, a few more lines of code at the end of each program will ultimately resolve the problem - albeit in a roundabout way. Perhaps the simplest solution is the best.
